# How to give dynamic expression path for file location (Wildcard file paths) in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am getting every data single excel file in my data lake. My container name is 'odoo' in the data lake. Excel files get stored in the folder called 'odoo' and below is the name of the file

report_2022-01-20.xlsx

I am using dataflow and I wanted to take everyday file using a wildcard path. Below is the dynamic expression I am trying to give but no success

```
/odoo/@concat('report_', string(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')), '.xlsx')
```

Can anyone advise me how to write the correct expression? I am a newbie to the adf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression looks fine. In your dataset, browse the container/folder and add the expression in the file path to get the file dynamically.

**Source file:**

[image]

`@concat('report_', string(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')), '.xlsx')`

[image]

Dataflow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Dataflow. This expression works in copy activity. Not working in dataflow

Comment: I used the above dataset in the dataflow source and it's working fine for me. Can you provide the screenshot of where you are providing your expression in dataflow?

Comment: @NiharikaMooka-MT Thanks. It's working now. My bad. I used wrong flow.

Comment: @NiharikaMoola If the container has multiple files like 
File_2024-01-02,
File_2024-01-03,
File_2024-01-04

Can we get the most updated file using expressions in the file path?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try: `@concat('/odoo/report_', formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '.xlsx')`

The string() might be causing the issue

Comment: It's coming error in /od00/@ - it says "Column not found" and also error in formatDateTime - It says unknown function name. Please advise